# Bootstrap Template not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently doing a website using Bootstrap. I chose this template (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) and copied the source code into my text editor. I am running the source code on Xamp using the local host but the carousel element is not being displayed.

Note: If you're viewing this page via a file:// URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.

What should I do please?

This is the code that I have in the head part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have on Xamp in a fiddle. This could be as easily is not having the proper links to bootstrap js and bootstrap css.

Comment: I have edited my post and displayed the code. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have the following correct links included in your code

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Because if not nothing is going to show because the dependent files are not accessible.

Comment: I have copied these into my text editor.  The carousel was displayed but the next and previous buttons are not working. Do you know what am I doing wrong pls? Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should call for `$('.carousel').carousel()`
Refer to: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I have copied the code from the link that you gave me but the next and previous controls are still not working.

Comment: ok can you edit your question by posting your page's HTML code? This way we can detect what's going wrong with your code!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import bootstrap-glyphicons.css after your stylesheet import.

HTML :

```
<!--Your stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
<!--To Add GlyphIcon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
```

That was my problem with a custom theme. They were using the original bootstrap link for the glyphicons:

CSS : bootstrap-theme.min.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')    format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

So you can import all these file in your project and relink them or simply use my first solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import bootstrap-glyphicons.css after your stylesheet import.

HTML :

```
<!--Your stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<!--To Add GlyphIcon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can go through this link: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/